# Multiple timeouts for request spring WebFLux

Tags: spring, kotlin, netty, webclient, spring-webflux

Hi im using webClient from spring webflux. i have some code like:

```
@Configuration
class WebClientConfig(
    @Value("\${url}")
    private val url: String
) {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    fun webClient(): WebClient {
        return createWebClient(700)
    }

    @Bean("more_timeout")
    fun webClientMoreTimeout(): WebClient {
        return createWebClient(3000)
    }

    private fun createWebClient(timeout: Int): WebClient{
        val httpClient = HttpClient.create()
            .tcpConfiguration { client -> client.option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, timeout) }
        return WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl(url)
            .clientConnector(ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
            .build()
    }
}
```

This configuration is because i need calls with different timeout. Supose i have one service A which is very importart for my response so i want to wait for the response maximum 3 seconds, and supose y have another services B, C, etc. which are not very important for my response, i will only wait 700ms to generate the response. Who can i archive this? 
The previous config is not working because webClient is inmutable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do it at webClient level, but you can do it at Reactor level, something like:

```
 return webClient.post()
        .uri { uriBuilder ->
            uriBuilder.path(PATH)
                .build()
        }
        .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(Request()))
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
        .exchange()
        .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(1000L))
```